# Power Gating a Comparator

Tags: comparator, zero-crossing

I am using a comparator (TS3021) as a zero crossing detector (ZCD). The ZCD toggles its output based on the zero crossings of a sine wave generated across a transformer coil. One end of the coil is connected to the +ve input of the comparator via a voltage divider and the other end of the coil is connected to the -ve input of the comparator. The comparator is powered from a 2.5V LDO output supplied by a 3V battery source. The voltage swing of the sine wave is less < (VDD-VSS) of the comparator and doesn't violate the common mode voltage requirements (rail-to-rail) of the comparator. I tested this configuration and I was able to see the comparator output toggle at the zero crossings.

[image]

The comparator doesn't have a shut-down/enable pin and consumes around 73 uA of quiescent current. I do not need the ZCD to operate continuously, hence I tried to disable the comparator by inserting an NMOS transistor between the negative supply and the VSS pin of the comparator to cut the tail current. I connected the gate of the MOSFET to VSS to test if it disables the tail current. I noticed that the output of the comparator still toggles, but doesn't go all the way to the negative rail. Also, the VDS voltage is around 0.2V. When I connect the gate of the MOSFET to VDD, I am able to resume normal operation with full rail-to-rail output swing. My question is regarding the case when gate of the MOSFET is tied to VSS. *Why  is the output still toggling when I have cut (I assume I have) the tail current? Is there a better way of implementing shut-down functionality?*

Comment: *"Is there a better way of implementing shut-down functionality?"*  Yes.  Use a comparator or opamp with shutdown.

Comment: Probably current is flowing to GND through the inverting terminal (which is grounded). Technically, by grounding the inverting terminal, and cutting off the flow of current from the VSS pin to GND, you are exposing the comparator to a common mode voltage far below VSS, which is probably not allowed (unless this is a very special comparator). If you want to disconnect the comparator from power, you will need to simultaneously disconnect all the inputs and outputs from any source of power, including bias networks or pullups or pulldowns.

Comment: I don't think a [CD4066](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b-q1.pdf) would work down to 3.0v reliably, but something like this could disconnect the other inputs quite easily. Easier yet is as Olin suggests, just get a comparator with a shutdown pin.

Comment: Not a good circuit because the top of the transformer coil will go negative with respect to ground so you are mistaken in believing it is OK.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I have looked into comparators with shut-down feature ([link](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b-q1.pdf)LMV761). Please note that the circuit I am working on is a low power one (<10uA @ 2.5V). I am not getting the right combination of propagation delay and the quiescent current needed for my application. Also, the LMV761 has a turn-on time (from shut-down) of 6us, which is not desirable in my case. Then we have the ADCMP608 which has a turn-on time of 150 ns, however the leakage current during shut-down is around 250 uA, which again is not desirable in my case.

Comment: @OlinLathrop ... The only option which is remotely close to my specification is MAX9030. However, I would like to see if I can make something  like above to work.

Comment: @mkeith Is it violating Common mode voltage because I am keeping the GND pin of the comparator floating? Also, how can current exit the comparator through the input pin, if the +ve and -ve terminals of the comparator are connected to the gate of a MOSFET as in a standard [differential pair](http://www.intechopen.com/source/html/18022/media/image66.jpeg). I understand that is not a valid assumption without knowing the internal details of the comparator. Could it be through protection diodes?

Comment: @Andyaka The condition I have mentioned in the figure i.e. Vinp-p < VDD-VSS will take care of this problem I believe. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Yes, through the protection diodes is what I was thinking. I would not consider the VSS pin to be floating. It is pulled up toward VDD by the internal circuitry of the IC (through bias current pathways). This is why I say that you are connecting the inverting terminal to a voltage far below VSS. In general, no IC pin can have power applied to it when the IC is de-powered. Any IC that can tolerate this condition is special, and the datasheet will probably call attention to it.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you. In that case, would it help if I added one more PMOS to the VDD rail and cut the power supply altogether?

Comment: Since you said the circuit was working, I didn't really think about it. But there is something to what @Andyaka says. You have grounded one side of the coil to VSS, right? The other side will go both high and low with respect to VSS. You need to bias the coil's DC point to mid-rail, and set your zero-crossing threshold also to mid-rail.

Comment: @mkeith The ground shown in the figure is not the circuit's ground. It's above VSS. VSS is the negative most voltage in the entire circuit and since I am using a voltage divider, the voltage seen by the comparator is not going to exceed its CM Voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea, based on your existing  circuit. Basically, you need to modify the circuit so that all pathways to GND are cut off by the NMOS. See below. I think this may work, but I really can't say I recommend it. It would be so much easier to find a component with an acceptable quiescent current, or a shutdown pin. Also, if you do this, you need to make sure that the output of the comparator has no path to GND. It is OK if the output is pulled up to VDD, or is floating (connected to CMOS input of a powered up device), but there cannot be any type of pulldown or anything that will sink current to GND.

[image: alternate-switch-idea]